# Compiling native node addon with c++ 17 inside fails during npm install on ubuntu

Tags: c++, node.js, gcc, c++17

I have native add-on for nodejs that uses c++17 features, specifically "shared_mutex". 
When I call npm install which downloads and compiles the add-on i get an error:
[image]

The linux machine has GCC 6.0 installed.

My Binding.gyp uses the following config to catch os type and add flags accordingly:

```
     'conditions': [
        ['OS=="linux"', {
            'CXXFLAGS': [
                '-std=c++1z'
            ]}],
```

** i've also tried with '-std=c++17', '-std=c++1z'.

What am I missing?

Update:
1. Updated ubuntu 16.04 to GCC 16.04 and made it default.
2. It seems that when i try to compile it manualy using node-gyp rebuild "CXXFLAGS='-std=c++17'" it works and brings only one error:
"shared_,utex in namespace std does not name a type std::shared_mutex file mutex" (the last error)

Comment: Firstly, c++1y is 14 not 17, 17 would be 1z. Secondly, try using cxxflags instead of cflags.

Comment: Do you see the `-std=c++1y` passed to `gcc` while compiling. The gcc command will be just above the error messages

Comment: `shared_mutex` was added in 6.1. (Note that the C++17 standard isn't finished yet. Compiler support is unpredictable.)

Comment: updated to CXXFLAGS="-std=c++1z" - still doesn't pass the flags.

Comment: i've updated the GCC to 6.3 but it still doesn't work with same error. But it seem to partly work when i manually "node-gyp rebuild CXXFLAGS=-std=c++17"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved. For anyone who has the same issue, bind.gyp should use cflags_cc instead of cxxflags.